# Problem loading spatialite extension with sqlite3 Python connector

Tags: python, spatial-database, spatialite, sqlite

I am trying to load the Spaltialite extension using SQLite3 python module. I am getting the following error when I run my script.

> EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\folder1\TestDB.sqlite')
conn.enable_load_extension(True)

conn.execute("select load_extension('libspatialite-4.dll')")


for row in conn.execute('SELECT AsText(Geometry) FROM alaska'):
    print row
```

I am able to connect to this db and run a non-spatial query without any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In native (out of the box) Python installations extensions are [disabled within sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#f1). Unfortunately this means that you will need to build the base pysqlite2 library manually and use that instead.

On Windows this will mean that you need a C compiler (Visual Studio comes with one - I've used Visual Studio 2010 for this before). However (with massive props) [Christoph Gholke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysqlite) provides a pysqlite2 download that does have the extensions enabled by default. I haven't tested these binaries with 3rd party extensions though, so for a guarantee I'd try building it myself.

1. First download the [pysqlite2 package](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite).
2. In `setup.cfg` comment out the `define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` so the config looks like:

`[build_ext]
    #define=
    #include_dirs=/usr/local/include
    #library_dirs=/usr/local/lib
    libraries=sqlite3
    #define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION`

1. Build from scratch with `python setup.py build_static install`. This will download and build the sqlite3 libraries for you.

We can then test this in Python with the following:

```py
import pysqlite2.dbapi2 as sqlite3 #alias over the top of the standard sqlite3 module

conn = sqlite3.connection(":memory:")

### NOTE: Don't use the following line with Christolph Gholke's build - extensions are enabled by default
conn.enable_load_extension(True)

#Now test extensions are working by trying the inbuilt rtree extension
conn.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE testrtree USING rtree(id,minX,maxX,minY,maxY);")

#then you can try loading spatialite
conn.execute("select load_extension('libspatialite-4.dll')")
```

Assuming that's all worked with no errors thrown then you should be good to go using spatialite in Python.